# Javascript scroll function called at page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**I'm trying to create a hyperlink that when clicked, will scroll to position 2500.**

Hyperlink:
    home

```
function scrollWin(amount) {
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 2500}, 800); 
}

window.onload = function(){ 
    var projectLink = document.getElementById('homeLink');
    projectLink.addEventListener = scrollWin(2500);
};
```

The part in the window.onload is working, but is being called when the page loads. I only want it to scroll when the link has been clicked. **What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: _“What am I doing wrong?”_ – you are _calling_ your function, instead of assigning the _reference_ to it as event handler. (And even if you make that just a reference, this is not how `addEventListener` works …)

Comment: Attach an event to addEventListener (`foo.addEventListener('click', do_stuff())`)

Comment: Then how does it work? I got the same result with projectLink.onclick =

Comment: Or bind it in jQuery (`$('#homelink').on('click', do_stuff())`)

Comment: @SenorAmor With that, it's still being called with onload

Comment: Why don't you put up a fiddle and show us? :)

Comment: @SenorAmor Uhm it works even less on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kgLyqd6p/

Comment: See:  http://jsfiddle.net/senoramor/kgLyqd6p/1/

Comment: That works on JSFiddle, but not on my website. When I click the link, the page scrolls to the point for waay less than a second then goes back up?

Comment: Likely the default action of your link (#) taking you back to the top.  Try preventing it like so:  http://jsfiddle.net/senoramor/kgLyqd6p/2/

Comment: Nope, still stays at top. Wanna move this to the chat? Feel like this is becoming too long

Comment: Not sure how it can work on the fiddle and not on your site unless you're not doing it the same on your site, sorry.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked the most simple thing, the href="#", sorry, thanks!

Comment: Excellent!  Glad to hear it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no scroll scientist, but if you're using jQuery for the scroll, couldn't you use it to bind the click handler?

```
function scrollWin(amount) {
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: amount}, 800); 
}

$(function () {
    $("#homeLink").on("click", function () {
        scrollWin(2500);
    });
});
```

Comment: I already found the problem, apparently you need a hashtag in the href=""

Comment: @SenorAmor - I'd bow down to you, but I'm on the pot.